# Most used tables in MySQL database server

Tags: mysql

Can somebody please help me with a query that lists the most used tables in a MySQL database? Or how can i find out the most used tables in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Percona added this feature to Percona Server, http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/user_stats.html?id=percona-server:features:userstatv2

Answer (score 1):

show open tables might help you or you can view queries from general log if enabled. You can also check binary logs from mysqlbinlog utility for further analysis.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL WorkBench is available from [MYSQL Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).
Very useful, once you install it go to `Performance > Performance Reports >  Database Schema Statistics > Schema Tables Statistics`.
You can see all tables that been used, sort out the list by number of I/O Reads, for example and then you can see your most frequently read tables.
You can sort a list of tables by number of updated rows/inserted rows/update time and etc.
MYSQL Workbench is a very useful tool.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to see these statistics over time? we have some old tables that we don't use anymore. I want to find them.